# How to describe an $\ell _p$ sequence space properly?

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

There are many ways to explain $\ell _p$ space, but how to make it into a single math notation?

It is my guess that a space of infinite sequences of real numbers can be defined as

$
\ell ^p ( \mathbb{R}) :=
\left\{ \mathbf{v} = (v_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \ \Bigg| \ 
\left\| \mathbf{v} \right\| _p <  \infty \right\}
\ \ \text{for any} \ p \in \mathbb{R}^+
$.

Is it correct? Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You should specify where the $v_n$ lie in (presumably, $\mathbb{R}$). Provided the $p$-norm is understood by the reader, that is indeed a good definition.

Comment: Sorry for the edit. I thought I was commenting.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Ohh, do you mean that $\mathbf{v} = (v_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \ , v_n \in \mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid circularity and be a bit more explicit, I'd go with:

$$\ell_p(\Bbb R):=\left\{v=(v_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}\in\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}\,\middle\vert\, \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left\lvert v_n\right\rvert^p<\infty\right\}$$

Comment: How about the range of $p$? $0 < p < \infty$?

Comment: Personally, I'd write $$$$ **Definition:** Given a real number $p>0$, we define $$(\text{stuff})_p$$ Typically, the most used ones are with $p\ge 1$. You must dedicate a whole special case to $\ell_\infty(\Bbb R)$.